# Importing a module in Python from a string

Tags: python

I have a string `type` with a value of "MBSquareObject". `MBSquareObject` is class in a file called `MBObject`. I want to import `MBSquareObject` dynamically.

If the square object was in a file of its own, this works:

```
__import__(type)
```

However, what I want to do is the equivalent of `from MBObject import MBSquareObject`. However, this doesn't work:

```
from MBObject __import__(type)
```

How else could I do this?

Edit: the answers given are assuming that MBSquareObject is some sort of object on MBObject, but it's just another class. MBSquareObject is a subclass of MBObject, so they are listed in the same file.

Edit: for some reason none of the answers are working. Here's what I have:

```
# this is imported at the top of the file
from MBObject import MBObject
type = 'MBSquareObject'
__import__('MBObject', globals(), locals(), [type])
object_class = eval(type)
object = object_class()
```

Error: NameError: name 'MBSquareObject' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example indicates that the module name `MBObject` doesn't need to be accessed dynamically, only the object inside.  In that case, you can just do

```
import MBObject
thing  = getattr(MBObject, type)
```

Edit: One problem is that you are giving your module and class the same name, which makes it difficult to distinguish them in your code.  You're getting confused between classes and modules.  You have *two* things called MBObject.  One is a module, the other is a class inside that module.  When you do `from MBObject import MBObject`, you import the class, but give yourself no reference to the module, making it awkward to subsequently import a second class (MBSquartObject) from the same module.

You can get the effect you want by using the code I gave above, but you must *not* do `from MBObject import MBObject` --- when you do that, you don't give yourself a reference to the module, only the class in that module.  Instead, just do `import MBObject` and then access the MBObject class via `MBObject.MBObject`.

If you want to be able to refer to both the MBObject class and other classes from the same module without prefixing them with the module name, give the module a different name.  Python style guidelines advise naming modules in all lowercase and classes in MixedCase.  So name your module mbobject.py.  Then you can do:

```
import mbobject
from mbobject import MBObject
thing = getattr(mbobject, type)
```

In general it is not a good idea in Python to give the same name to a module and a class.  Modules and classes are different things, and giving them the same name can lead to confusions like this where you're not clear on whether you're dealing with the module or the class.

Comment: Wait I'm sorry I should have specified: MBSquareObject is a class, a subclass of MBObject. They are just placed in the same file.

Comment: @mohabitar what is the file called? If it is named `MBObject.py`, then this should work. In this case `MBObject` refers to the module name, not the class name.

Comment: @mohabitar: In that case you need to edit your question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.  `from MBObject import MBSquareObject` will import a thing (class, number, string, whatever) from a *module* called `MBObject`.  Do you know the name of the module you're trying to import from, or does that also have to be determined dynamically, and if so, how?  (That is, are you determining the module separately from the class, or are they somehow linked?)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky the name of the file is MBObject.py, and it has two classes: MBObject and MBSquareObject(subclass of MBObject)

Comment: @mohabitar: Then my answer will work, as long as you know you are always importing from MBObject.py, and not dynamically from some as-yet-undetermined file.

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: type object 'MBObject' has no attribute 'MBSquareObject'

Comment: @mohabitar: Have you already imported the `MBObject` class before you try to do the dynamic import?  If so, maybe don't do that.  (This is one reason why it's often not a good idea to give Python classes the same name as their module.)  Please edit your question to give the complete context of your code.

Comment: @mohabitar: I've edited my answer.  My original code will work if you don't do `from MBObject import MBObject` first.  If you want to import the class and the module, you should give your module a different name from the class inside it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and I like this way because it's much cleaner than the other answers

Answer (score 3):

[`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) can take additional arguments specifying exactly which objects should be imported. From the return of this function you can fetch whatever object you desire.

```
source_module = 'MBObject'
object_in_module = 'MBSquareObject'

obj = getattr(__import__(source_module, globals(), locals(), [object_in_module]),
              object_in_module)
```

Comment: `__import__` returns the imported module — you need to store that return value as in the example. The import won't be automatically added to the global scope (for that, `from x import y` would work just fine).

Comment: So I would use that instead of `object_class = eval(type)`?

Comment: Yes. You can wrap the `getattr` call around the `__import__` call to fetch the exact object within the module and nothing else.

Comment: It neither works here. I guess you can not use `__import__` inline like that. The [answer below by David Z](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13353536/2066215), provides a similar, but functional, solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module = __import__('MSObject', globals(), locals(), ['MBSquareObject'], -1)
```

Plugged together using the examples found here:

[http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#**import**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

Answer (score 1):

The full syntax of the `__import__` function is described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

```
 __import__(name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])
```

Here `fromlist` is the list of items to import from the imported module. A statement like

```
 from module import object1, object2
```

is implemented as something like

```
module = __import__('module', globals(), locals(), ['object1', 'object2'])
object1 = getattr(module, 'object1')
object2 = getattr(module, 'object2')
```

So in your case, you could use

```
module = __import__('MBObject', globals(), locals(), [type])
the_object = getattr(module, type)
```

In recent versions of Python, since 3.1, there is a module [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html) which you can presumably use to do this. Though the only way I can find to do so is to use the module's implementation of `__import__`, which is basically the same as the built-in implementation, so I guess you might as well use the built-in one.

Comment: No, this is not what you tried. Or at least what you edited into your question is not what any of the answers are telling you to do. Try actually using the code I've given you before you say it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
module = __import__('MSObject.' + 'MBSquareObject')
```